# Cordova can't find ant but I have Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, cordova, aptana

I'm trying to install cordova and I'm stuck on adding android platform.
cordova platform add android says that I don't have ant installed. And I don't because I'm using Aptana (Eclipse). 
Can I force cordova to use eclise  or I have to install ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Eclipse home Directory -->  Plugins --> find 'org.apache.ant_?.?.?.v?????'`

Then add the `bin` folder in there to your system path.  Cordova should find it then.

Comment: no use:/ I found c:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030\bin\ and added it to path as well as new var - always the same error

Comment: If I type ant in command lin I get: Buildfile: build.xml deos not exist! Build failed.

Comment: If you type ant -v in command line and it shows the version then it means it's working correctly for the system. If you do ant alone it will try to find the build.xml to build the project.  So if it is working just check crdova and make sure it is not complaining about finding ant.

Comment: After restarting command line it went good. thx. But I stilol have other error because of polish letter "Ł". Can I simply use files from github?

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Remember, after every change to the system path you need to restart the applications (including cmd.exe) to get the updated system variables.  Don't forget to accept the answer read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Tell me... Can I simply copy files from https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/3.2.x to my aptana project? Which files?

Comment: Check the readme.  You can add anything if it makes sense.  You can just have the source files, compile them then use it or directly use the classes.  It depends on the needs and the way you want to build it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42736/discussion-between-piernik-and-hitham-s-alqadheeb)